# $\lim_n \min(q,x_n)$ exists for all $q \in \mathbb{Q}^+$ implies $\lim_n x_n$ exists in $\overline{\mathbb{R}}^+$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

The following property was used to verify the convergence of a sequence $(x_n)_n$ in $\overline{\mathbb{R}}^+:$ if for all $q \in \mathbb{Q}^+,(\min(x_n,q))_n$ converges then $(x_n)_n$ converges in $\overline{\mathbb{R}}^+.$

Any idea how to prove this property ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $q_{i}>L$ be fixed, where $q_{i}\in\mathbb{Q}^{+}$.

Also let $\limsup x_{n}=\lim_{k}x_{n_{k}}=L$ and $\liminf x_{n}=\lim_{l}x_{m_{l}}=M$, then $L=\min(L,q_{i})=\lim_{k}\min(x_{n_{k}},q_{i})$.

Keep in mind that both $\{\min(x_{n_{k}},q_{i})\}_{k}$ and $\{\min(x_{m_{l}},q_{i})\}_{l}$ are subsequences of the convergent sequence $\{\min(x_{n},q_{i})\}_{n}$, hence $\lim_{k}\min(x_{n_{k}},q_{i})=\lim_{l}\min(x_{m_{l}},q_{i})$. On the other hand, $\lim_{l}\min(x_{m_{l}},q_{i})=\min(M,q_{i})$.

We conclude that $L=\min(M,q_{i})$, taking $q_{i}\downarrow L$ we get $L=\min(M,L)$, this shows that $L\leq M$ and hence $L=M$.

Comment: Came up with another way, $x \to \min(x,q),$ is in increasing so for all $q \in \mathbb{N},\limsup_n \min(q,x_n)=\liminf_n\min(x_n,q),$ so for all $q \in \mathbb{N},\min(\limsup_n x_n,q)=\min(\liminf_n x_n,q)$ then we take the limit $q \to \infty,$ to obtain $\limsup_n x_n =\liminf_n x_n$

Comment: Okay it looks working.